# ASP.NET Core: How to skip running authentication on [AllowAnonymous]

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

How to identify if authentication is not needed for current request?

We have a custom authentication handler, simplified here:

```
internal class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
{
    static readonly string[] DontCheckAuth = new string[] { "/servers", "/user/profile/", "/highscore/list", "/highscore/metadata/" };

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        /*
            if url contains any of DontCheckAuth
                then return AuthenticateResult.NoResult()
            else
                do custom auth
        */
    }
}
```

So everything works OK, but `HandleAuthenticateAsync` is run on every request, even on URLs I have marked as `[AllowAnonymous]`. Currently I just check the URL and compare it to hard-coded list of URLs that does not require authentication.

How can I automate this process so I don't have to manually update the list of URLs (which I forget to do for new APIs)?